# char cannot be dereferenced Java when trying to input Char and using compareTo

Tags: java, if-statement, char, compareto, charat

So I'm fairly new to java and I've been stuck on this question.

> Prompt the user for two characters and store them in two char
>   variables.  Compare the variables and print “ is less than
>   ” if the first char is less than the second char. 
>   Otherwise, print “ is greater than ” if the
>   first char is greater than the first char.  Otherwise, print
>   “ is equal to ” if they are equal.
>
> If user enters ‘A’ then ‘B’ print: A is less than B If user enters ‘B’
>   then ‘A’ print: B is greater than A If user enters ‘A’ then ‘A’ print:
>   A is equal to A

Note: The output above would be printed if the user entered the characters A and B.  If the user enters other letters, those letters would be printed.  This is the power of variables!

```
 Scanner letter = new Scanner(System.in);
 String input;
 char firstChar;
 char secondChar;

 System.out.println("Enter two characters:");

 input = letter.nextLine();
 firstChar = input.charAt(0);
 input = letter.nextLine();
 secondChar = input.charAt(0);



  if (firstChar.compareTo(secondChar) < 0)
 {
 System.out.println(firstChar+ " is less than " +secondChar+ "");
 }

  if (firstChar.compareTo(secondChar) > 0)
 {
 System.out.println(firstChar+ " is greater than " +secondChar+ "");
 }

  if (firstChar.compareTo(secondChar) == 0)
 {
 System.out.println(firstChar+ " is equal to " +secondChar+ "");
 }
```

I'm not sure if I need the String or not or if I can just use
firstChar = letter.next().charAt(0);

Comment: What's the question? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get a char cannot be dereferenced error starting at                                                      if (firstChar.compareTo(secondChar) < 0) so I suppose all my if statements are off?

Comment: Post the full error with trace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way that you are **using** the `firstChar` variable etcetera.

```
  char firstChar; // OK

  firstChar = input.charAt(0); // OK

  if (firstChar.compareTo(secondChar) < 0)   // FAIL!
```

The `char` type is a primitive type.  You can't call methods on a `char`.

You need to operate on character values directly ... using numeric, relational or bitwise operators; e.g.

```
  if (firstChar < secondChar))
```

---

What you were trying to do *would have* worked if the type of `firstChar` was `Character` not `char`.  But in this case, using `char` is simpler, faster, less code, etcetera.